# Connection to Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

How to connect to Cloud SQL instance and insert values in a particular database from an external web application using PHP or Javascript?

Comment: A bit more details would be welcome...

Comment: I want to write a code in Javascript or PHP to connect to Cloud SQL instance and insert values in the particular database.

Comment: Still lacking... From where do you want to connect? Do you know how to connect to a MySQL database with either javascript or php?

Comment: I want to know how to connect to a Cloud SQL db with JS or PHP

Comment: Yes... My question is still good... Are you in the same gcp project? Another gcp project? Do you know how to connect to a MySQL database with either JavaScript or PHP? Depending on what you say, my answer will not be the same...

Comment: I know how to connect to a MySQL database. I am looking for how to connect to a Cloud SQL database.

Comment: There you go, now from where do you connect? Same project or another?

Comment: trying to do it in the same project

Answer (score 0):

The best way to connect to a CloudSQL instance inside the same gcp project is to use private ip, this way you won't need to use the CloudSQL proxy with a service account used to authenticate through the google API. That way is faster and more secure as you do not risk a mistake in the IAM.

To configurate private IP you juste need to follow this doc: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip

Then you just have to connect to the CloudSQL instance using the IP as you would do for any other non local database.

Comment: what should be the connection string pattern?

Comment: What do you mean connection string pattern? You use the account you created in your CloudSQL instance console to connect with the ip you created, same as any other database...

Comment: Sure I ll try this right away. Thanks for the help!